# GLM::Rotate seems to cause wrong rotation?

Tags: c++, rotation, glm-math

Simply put, I'm learning OpenGL and am starting to learn about transform matrices. Below is my current code:

```
glm::vec4 myPosition(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

glm::vec3 rotationAxis(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

glm::mat4 scalar = glm::scale(glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));
glm::mat4 rotator = glm::rotate(360.0f, rotationAxis);
glm::mat4 translator = glm::translate(glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));

glm::mat4 transform = translator * rotator * scalar;

myPosition = transform * myPosition;
```

As far as I can tell, I'm doing this in the correct order: Scale -> Rotate -> Translate. So, I have the scale set to do nothing because I don't actually want it to scale anywhere (for simplicity sake).

Next, I set rotate to 360.0f on (correct me if I'm wrong) the Y axis. This should return to the original point, at least that's what I would think from a 360 degree rotation around a singular axis.

Then, I set it to translate 1 unit in every direction to make sure it moves.

After finishing this all, I have commented out the rotator line, and it works fantastic, even if I change the scale. However, whenever I add in the rotate line the final position is not a normal 360 degree rotation?

I have configured my program to output the position vector both before transforms and after.

The before position is (1, 1, 1)

The after position is (1.67522, 2, -0.242607).

I have been struggling to find my error, literally all day so if anyone can help me find what I'm doing wrong, it would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Also, the rotationAxis vector is created there so that it's easy to find and read correctly. The final product will just initialize that vector within the rotate's arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation at http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.7/api/a00236.html (for the latest released version right now), glm::rotate(..) takes in an angle expressed in degrees.

However, changing your rotation matrix line

```
glm::mat4 rotator = glm::rotate(360.0f, rotationAxis);
```

to

```
glm::mat4 rotator = glm::rotate(3.141592f * 2.0f, rotationAxis);
```

which is just 2*PI fixes this.

This means that the angle should be in radians rather than in degrees. Tested on my machine with GLM 0.9.7.1-1. This is either a mistake in the documentation or in the GLM code itself.

From my experience with GLM (some time ago, might've been an earlier version) these kinds of functions should take a degrees angle by default, and the `#define GLM_FORCE_RADIANS` macro is what makes them calculate in radians. It is possible that the author made this the default behaviour and forgot to update the docs.

On a side note, you should probably not be using `scalar` as the name for a glm::mat4 value, since a scalar in mathematics is just a single real number rather than a matrix: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_%28mathematics%29

Comment: Thank you, I'm assuming you're correct. And I know the naming convention isn't correct, this is just playing around with Matrices and seeing if I get the proper results, so I haven't been descriptive on my names. I'm gonna try it now!

Comment: Yep, that worked. They should really change that in the documentation but it's whatevs. Thanks a bunch

Comment: I wasted an embarrassing amount of time on this bug. Now that we know it needs radians, in GLM 9.7.1 there is a function `glm::radians` that does degrees to radians for you.